Moving mouse cursor to a tRectangle's center
While dragging a tRectangle, I'm trying to move the mouse cursor
to it's center point.
Note: the tRectangle moves at 10 x pixels count
for each pixel the mouse cursor moves.
Follows a code snippet showing how I'm doing so far.
procedure SetMouseCursorPosToCenter (const aTargetControl: tRectangle);
var MouseCursorPos : tPointF;
begin
  MouseCursorPos := aTargetControl.LocalToScreen ((aTargetControl.Left + Width )/2),         
                                                   (aTargetControl.Top  + Height)/2));
  SetCursorPos (Round (MouseCursorPos.X), Round (MouseCursorPos.Y)) // should move the cursor to the center
end;                                                                //   of aTargetControl
                                                                    // actually seems that has no effect upon
                                                                    //   mouse cursor position

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

How do you move the Rectangle? Do you use the FireMonkey Drag&Drop functions? Keep in mind that setting the mouse cursor position will result in another mouse move event. What is Width referring to you your code? SetCursorPos must also consider screen dpi.

Hi Sebastian. As you  should already picture, aTargetControl is the control that is being dragged out.
Left, Top are  its local coordinates.
Height, Width are, by all means, aTargetControl height and width.

Yes, I can imagine that Width and Height should be the dimensions of aTargetControl. But that example doesn't show that. That makes it difficult to help you because we don't even know if your real issue is calculating the center of the aRectangle in screen coordinates, or something else.

At Sebastian. Yes. My mistake.
The correct sintax of the statement is:
MouseCursorPos := aTargetControl.LocalToScreen ((aTargetControl.Left + aTargetControl.Width )/2),
(aTargetControl.Top  + aTargetControl.Height)/2));

do u have zoom controls? u have to consider it too if u do

MouseCursorPos := aTargetControl.LocalToScreen (aTargetControl.Left + aTargetControl.Width/2), aTargetControl.Top + aTargetControl.Height/2));
